# firestore python do not overwrite data

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-firestore

i have this in a collection:

```
resul = {
  'name': 'bob',
  'position': 'ceo',
 }
```

when i run a python code again with a different position value a new data , it's overwriting  the position and i dont want it to

result i want:

```
resul = { 
         'name':'bob',
         'position':'ceo',
         'age':25,
    }
```

result i am getting:

```
resul = { 
         'name':'bob',
         'position':'co-founder',
         'age':25,
    }
```

code using:

```
info_dic={}
info_dict.update(resul)
         
infoREferenc = db.collection(u'test').document(u'bob')
        
infoREferenc.set({"general":info_dic}, merge=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the field(ex. `position`,`age`,`name`) is existing in your map(`general`) it will just update the value of the field. If not, it will write the field and insert with its value. I suggest add a new field in your map for additional position, for example:

```py
info_dic={
    u'name': u'bob',
    u'position':u'ceo',
    u'secondary-position': u'co-founder',
    'age': 26
}
         
infoREferenc = db.collection(u'test').document(u'bob')
        
infoREferenc.set({'general':info_dic}, merge=True)
```